# Laravel eager loading with two Fk to same table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I want use Eager loading in Laravel 8 with a relations of two foreign keys to the same table.

`Teams table`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 120 | Germany |
| 245 | Italy |

`Fixtures table`

| id | timestamp | home_id | away_id | winner_id | home_goals | away_goals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1607803200 | 120 | 245 | 120 | 2 | 0 |

`Fixture Model`

```php
public function home()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, "home_id");
}

public function away()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, "away_id");
}

public function winner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, "winner_id");
}
```

In controller, even with `$fixtures = Fixture::with(["home", "away", "winner"])->get();` the [N+1 Query detector](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-query-detector) package advise me from that problem.

Are there any way to use eager loading with multiple foreign keys belongs to the same table??
If not, any suggestions to modify the database structure in any better way?

Thank you!

**UPDATED:**
Add the requested info. Seen in the laravel debugbar now, I see only one duplicate query and I think it´s makes sense, are the two relations loaded in with..
So, it´s correct?

Using the data in the view:

```
@foreach($fixtures as $fixture)
    <div class="flex items-center ">
        <div>
            <img class="object-scale-down h-12 w-12 border border-indigo-600" src="{{ $fixture->home->logo }}" />
        </div>
        <div class="flex-auto ml-5">
            {{ $fixture->home->name }}
        </div>
        <div class="flex-auto">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-auto mr-5 text-right">
            {{ $fixture->away->name }}
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <div>
                <img class="object-scale-down h-12 w-12 border border-indigo-600" src="{{ $fixture->away->logo }}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Data from Laravel DebugBar:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include the message from the N+1 Query package? Your code shouldn't be causing any. You do have some duplication in that `winner_id` will match `home_id` or `away_id`, but that's not really an N+1 issue. Unless you executing some code in a loop that calls more queries, what you've posted shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Added the info requested.. Maybe, it's all ok? And for winner_id, any other idea to do this?

Comment: Yeah, the error should say something like `Relation: winner, add with('winner')`, etc. I'm not sure why it's thinking that `App\Models\Team` is a relationship, when that's obviously the class, and not the method name. And for `winner_id`, not really. That approach is ok, but it might be better to simply do `public function getWinnerAttribute() { return $this->home_id == $this->winner_id ? $this->home : $this->away; }`, then `$fixture->winner` would return the pre-loaded `$fixture->home` or `$fixture->away` Team record.

Comment: I like the aproach for the `winner_id`.. Thank you for your help!